# How to assign external DNS name to Docker containers

Tags: domain-name-system, docker, containers

How do I assign DNS names directly to my Docker containers? This is a fairly broad question so as to avoid an X/Y problem - I'll try to explain what I've done but feel free to suggest another path.

Right now my idea is to create DNS names in my resolver, and route those to an IP dedicated to each container. Many containers will have overlapping ports, so I have been attempting to use the `macvlan` driver to assign them separate IP addresses. These are attached to network interface just for containers. Some of my efforts are shown in [this Reddit thread](https://old.reddit.com/r/docker/comments/b9zaj8/frustrated_with_trying_to_use_macvlan/) - but so far, I have not been successful in routing either in or out of the container when using `macvlan`.

Is there a recommended way of just having one Docker host, with multiple services on port 80/443 (or other common ports) routed out to `one.example.com`, `two.example.com` etc?

Comment: OK, I think I see where you're going. AFAIK most people still use a web proxy container such as jwilder/nginx-proxy and don't bother with unique external IP addresses or macvlan.

Comment: I see. I'll try `nginx-proxy` and see how it works. Very much a different approach to `macvlan` but looks promising.

Answer (score 0):

After some further investigation, I have discovered a solution to this issue. Specifically, I was using an [older guide](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/get-started-macvlan/) to `macvlan`, which fails to mention that promiscuous mode must be enabled on your network adapter. The [latest guide](https://docs.docker.com/network/macvlan/) does mention this. As it turns out, this solves my problem perfectly - any and all services get their own IP, which I can then assign to a DNS entry in my resolver.

Comment: How are you registering the containers in DNS? Are you manually assigning them a specific IP in their docker-compose, or do you have some other DNS registration method that is automatic?